# Sharp thumbnails in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

I have a site where I list lots of thumbnails (photos) on the front page in a grid layout. Each image is 120px x 120px. What is the best way to keep them sharp on high resolution devices?

Should I make them 240px x 240px and then in the code resize them like:

```
<img src="file.jpg" width="120" hgith="120">
```

I guess jpg is better than png because of the files sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use it like you mention. no matter you r using png or jpg.

you can also set thumbnail size from WordPress setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
    <?php 
        $size=array(240,240);

        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, "attachment-thumbnail" ); 
    ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail